# Solving IVPs with one-sided initial condition using Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

Consider an initial value problem of first order linear ODE.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}y(t)+2y(t)=e^{-t}H(t),\lim_{t \to 0^-}y(t)=2$$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function. Let $L[y: t \to s]=Y(s)$ and applying Laplace Transform to both side of the equation.
$$sY(s)-y(0)+2Y(s)=\frac{1}{s+1}.$$
Then I find $y(t)$ to be
$$Y(s)=\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)}+\frac{1}{s+2}y(0) \Rightarrow y(t)=y(0)e^{-2t}+(e^{-t}-e^{-2t}).$$
My main question is whether it is appropriate to use $y(0^-)$ in this case as the value of $y(0)$, which in this case only the value of left sided limit is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the solution $y(t)=e^{-t}+e^{-2t}$ you obtained is only valid for $t>0$. For $t<0$ the solution of the now homogeneous equation is $y(t)=2e^{-2t}$, so that in total
$$
y(t)=2e^{-2t}+H(t)(e^{-t}-e^{-2t}).
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. This one would be more strict in a mathematical sense. I got the idea that the problem happens in inverse Laplace transform as $(s+1)^{-1}$ can be $e^{-t}$ and $e^{-t}u(t)$ at the same time. Thus, in this case I would now consider solving piecewise.

Comment: You would have to check with reliable sources, but it looks like any term having an initial condition as factor is valid globally, while all other terms get restricted to the positive half axis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because in the definition of Laplace transform we can state:

$$L\{f(t) \}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt=\int_{0^-}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

Since with Impulse response and Heaviside response, our functions are not differentiable at $t=0$, so we take Laplace Transform from $t=0^-$, without loss of generality.

This not a rigorous explanation by any means, but it should show you why we chose $0^-$ instead of $0$

Comment: Thank you for answering. Then, the question becomes if we do this, $y'(0^-)=-3$, but if we directly plug initial condition into the equation, $y'(0^-)=-4$. Will this be problematic?

Comment: This is a first order DE, so we only have one free parameter in the form of $y(0^-)$ so solving the DE only requires one initial value. In a second order DE, you would have 2 free parameters in form of $y(0^-)$ and $y'(0^-)$, in which case you would be asked to provide a solution in terms of BOTH initial values. Notice with a second order DE, upon taking L.T. we obviously have a dependance on $y$ and $y'$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a good point of the uniqueness and existence theorem of IVPs.